# How can you block ELF in the range of 2hz - 20hz?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

If our brains are emmiting em waves(https://engineering.mit.edu/engage/ask-an-engineer/can-brain-waves-interfere-with-radio-waves/), how can we effectively shield our brains from emitting such waves?

Comment: https://i.pinimg.com/originals/6e/9a/6a/6e9a6a673710b0d8411db4c81937e2a3.jpg

Comment: That wouldnt work....wavelength

Comment: From the article you link : "the magnetic field of the earth is just strong enough to move the needle of a compass. Signals from the brain are a billionth of that strength."  What possible reason is there to block such a signal ?  You have to put the brain in a shielded room and use the most sensitive detectors possible placed as close as possible to the brain to detect them.  To stop detection don't put the detector helmet on.

Comment: What if these signals could interact with one another....The us navy did use ELF to do underwater communicationhttps://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Sanguine....